# Simplest way to get a long URL for a shortened URL in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, short-url

What is the simplest way to retrieve the original URL for a short URL in Cocoa? Anything that can be done in just a few lines?

Comment: First, define short URL. Second, unless you have all of the parts of the original URL, you can't pull it out of thin air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: I just saw your comment and realised it's following the redirect.

See the delegate method: `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`, which tells you it's doing a redirect to this new request, based on the previous response.

You can get the expanded URL either from the new request here, or from the Location header of the redirect response.

> **Discussion** If the delegate wishes to
>   cancel the redirect, it should call
>   the connection object’s cancel method.
>   Alternatively, the delegate method can
>   return nil to cancel the redirect, and
>   the connection will continue to
>   process. This has special relevance in
>   the case where redirectResponse is not
>   nil. In this case, any data that is
>   loaded for the connection will be sent
>   to the delegate, and the delegate will
>   receive a connectionDidFinishLoading
>   or connection:didFailLoadingWithError:
>   message, as appropriate.

Original answer follows...

Use `NSURLConnection` with a delegate.  In your delegate's `connection:didReceiveResponse:` method, fetch `allHeaderFields` and read the value of the "Location" header.

Something like:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Expanded URL = %@", [[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Location"]);
}
```

I'd create a little `URLExpander` class to do this personally, with a signature something like:

```
+(void)asyncExpandURL:(NSURL *)aURL didExpandTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
```

Then just pass back two arguments in your message, one for the short URL, one for the long.

Comment: I'd make it an object and have it not retain the target. That way, you can release the object—and thereby cancel the request—if your object (e.g., document) goes away.

Comment: Hmmm...doesn't seem to be returning the "Location" header:

Comment: connection:didReceiveResponse: {
     "Cache-Control" = "max-age=300, must-revalidate";
     Connection = "Keep-Alive";
     "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
     Date = "Sun, 19 Dec 2010 01:54:10 GMT";
     Server = "Apache/2.2";
     "Set-Cookie" = "X-Mapping-edcdikko=AC17288FCF56ED010476BDE83D0C0E9D; path=/";
     "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
     Vary = "Accept-Encoding,Cookie";
     "Wp-Super-Cache" = "Served supercache file from PHP";
 }

Comment: Just added an update to my answer.  I hadn't realised it would follow redirects, but fortunately there's a delegate method (how convenient!) for this.

Comment: y u no post asyncExpandURL:didExpandTarget:selector: implementation code!?! [meme face] ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple way, you have to request the short-url-providing-server and get the full url. This must be done with a url connection and maybe some logic behind to get the redirect link (I haven't tried yet)

Comment: Also, it needn't be a full GET request either, HEAD should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to make the request and follow the redirects, a simpler way is to use a link-lengthening service. Here are two simple APIs:

- http://longurl.org/api/#expand-url
- http://www.longurlplease.com/docs

I may post some code snippets soon especially if there is interest.